# DotNetOpenAuth OnLoggedIn event never fired

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetopenauth

I am a fresher to use the DotNetOpenAuth. And I have download the latest version V3.4.6 from your website which includes samples.
But when I try to test the “OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms” project, it seems that the “OnLoggedIn=OpenIdLogin1_LoggedIn” event never been fired, so the friendly user name can never be displayed. And I also test the “OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc” project, after I logged in with Yahoo opened, it always give the following information “This message has already been processed. This could indicate a replay attack in progress.” It seems that I can always get this error message.

Further information: I test it in my company then got the above information; but when I go back home, I can successfully use all the DotNetOpenAuth examples and even my own codes with it can work well.

My computer OS in company is: Windows 7
My computer OS in home is: Windows Vista

Maybe the company network environment is different from the network environment at home??? Or maybe it is caused by different OS???

I have seen others to raise a similiar question which is also about "OnLoggedIn" event can not fire, but seems no one reply it.

Can you give any help about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problems. I finally found out that it is due to the configuration issue. I just add maxAuthenticationTime="0:10" in the openid section, that is: 
"openid maxAuthenticationTime="0:10"", 
then I can get the examples run normally. Maybe the default maxAuthenticationTime is less than 10? Maybe in some network environment, it needs more authentication time.

Anyway, thanks for your reply and your excellent work for openid.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be that your company network has a firewall that blocks something that OpenID needs if your site is on the internal network.  Impossible to say what for sure though, being on the outside.

The OS version shouldn't have anything to do with it, however.

Comment: It is said that the company network only allow outboudings but not allow inboudings, and it also installed the TMG 2010 inside company.